# Linux Ubuntu make command error 127

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile

Whenever I try to run the *make*-command, It gives me following error.

```
make: powerpc-fsl-linux-g++: Command not found
make: *** [main.o] Error 127
```

The obvious conclusion would be:
The command 'g++' was not found on your system, install it.
(*sudo apt-get install g++*)

However, the g++ command works perfectly, and is installed.
Also, my system does not have an active Internet connection, so I can't run any apt-get command successfully.

The *make*-command creates an output file, but I'm not sure if it's complete and working, since there is an error.
Also, the make install command displays the exact same error.

Any help, on how I can solve this Error?

Comment: have you installed the package `sudo apt-get install build-essential` ?

Comment: Note that the error message doesn't say it can't find `g++`, but that it can't find `powerpc-fsl-linux-g++`. I'm guessing you are trying to cross-compile something targeting Linux on a PowerPC platform? Then you need to install a compiler to handle that.

Comment: @KostasRim I already tried that, but since my System doesn't have a connection, it won't install anythin (AFAIK).

Is there a way to download it on a seperate computer and install it without an internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package [powerpc-fsl-linux-g++](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/g++-4.8-powerpc-linux-gnu).